# How to get the size and location of the taskbar with PyGTK?

Tags: python, pygtk, taskbar, area

Is there any way to get the position and size of the taskbar on Windows with PyGTK?

If not, is there at least a way to determine the free client area on a specific monitor? (In other words, the area the taskbar *does not* occupy?)

Comment: Why would you need this? I mean, you are drawing in your own window, anyway, even if it covers the whole screen except the taskbar. You could always check your own window size, couldn't you?

Comment: @abbot: I wanted to create a window that was positioned relative to the taskbar's position.

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize a window, and check its geometry after it was maximized. Something like this (works both on Windows and Linux):

```
import gtk

size = (10, 10)
def expose(widget, *args):
    global size
    size = widget.get_size()
    if size != (10, 10):
        gtk.main_quit()

win = gtk.Window()
win.resize(*size)
win.connect('expose-event', expose)
win.show()
win.maximize()
gtk.main()
print size
```

This is somewhat hackish, but I'm not sure if there is a portable way (without using Win32 API if you are on Windows) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly neater (but windows only) as this creates a dynamic pair of variables which you can then used to adjust the offset of your remaining code;

```
import win32gui

#discover where top left corner of active screen is
#return is a dictionary list of keys and values
monitors = win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors()
display1 = win32api.GetMonitorInfo(monitors[0][0])

#from the Work key, select the first and second values
x_adj=(display1['Work'][0])
y_adj=(display1['Work'][1])
```

Then, in the remainder of your code use these adjustments to refine your navigation clicks. In my case I am moving around a window using `pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui

#just move the mouse to a position
pyautogui.moveTo(x=103+x_adj, y=235+y_adj)

#move and click the mouse
pyautogui.click(x=103+x_adj, y=235+y_adj)
```

In your case you will want to create the top left corner of the new window at (or relative to) the co-ordinates of `(x_adj,y_adj)`